# Projecting onto an arbitrary subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem: let $V \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$, then seek an expression for $\widehat{x}_{V},$ the projection of $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ onto $V$.

The note I read first shows that $\widehat{x}_{V}=A\left(A^{T} A\right)^{-1} A^{T} x$, where $A=\left[\begin{array}{llll}v^{1} & v^{2} & \ldots & v^{m}\end{array}\right]$ and $v$'s are basis vectors of $V$. And $P=A\left(A^{T} A\right)^{-1} A^{T}$ is the projecting matrix.

Then it directly says that $P=p\left(p^{T} p\right)^{-1} p^{T}=\frac{1}{\|p\|^{2}} p p^{T}$, where $p$ is a basis for $V$. I cannot see how this comes from.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$p(p^\top p)^{-1} p^\top = \frac{1}{\|p\|^2} pp^\top$ only makes sense when $p$ is a single non-zero [column] vector. It is a special case of $A(A^\top A)^{-1} A^\top$ when $A$ has one column, i.e., it is the projection onto a one-dimensional subspace spanned by $p$.

Comment: So if we are projecting onto a multi-dimensional subspace, we cannot only use one basis vector to write an expression for the projection?

Comment: @Alalalalaki No, you have to use the $A(A^\top A)^{-1} A^\top$ form, where the columns of $A$ are the basis vectors.

Comment: What if we are projecting to a hyperplane $H=\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: p \cdot x=0\right\}$. It seems we can write the projection with only $p$. Does that mean this hyperplane is a one-dimensional subspace? Sorry if this is trivial, I am very new to the hyperplane stuff.

Comment: @Alalalalaki No, the hyperplane is $n-1$ dimensional; it is the orthogonal complement to the one-dimensional subspace spanned by $p$. The projection matrix onto $H$ is $(I - \frac{1}{\|p\|^2} pp^\top)$, i.e. you project $x$ onto the one-dimensional subspace spanned by $p$, and subtract this from the original vector $x$.

Comment: Thanks! You really make it clear. However I have a final question that when it is multi-dimensional, I know the projection is derived from $A^{T}(x-A \alpha)=0$, where $\alpha$ is a $m \times 1$ vector. However, when it is 1-dimensional, I find it difficult to write the analogy. Is it $p^{T}(x- p\alpha)=0$? What is the $\alpha$ now?